# Rails Custom Error Page Working and Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-500

ruby-2.3.7   Rails 5.1.4

I'm trying to learn about error pages in Rails apps: how to create them and how they get called/triggered.  I've read quite a few posts and blogs about this.  I've found several that use the same approach.  It seems simple enough, so I tried to implement it.

When I go directly to my new 404 or 500 page: `...myapp/404` or `...myapp/500` I get the correct custom 404/500 page. But when I trigger a different 500 error, I do not. I.e: `...myapp.employee/99999` throws an error because there is no such employee:

`500 Internal Server Error
If you are the administrator of this website, then please read this web application's log file and/or the web server's log file to find out what went wrong`

How do I get errors to go to my new error pages?

Code:

```
config/environments/development.rb:
-------
# see error pages in dev site
config.consider_all_requests_local = false # true


config/application.rb:
-------
# added for error pages
config.exceptions_app = self.routes


config/routes.rb
------
get "/404", to: "errors#not_found", :via => :all
get "/500", to: "errors#internal_server_error", :via => :all


controllers/errors_controller.rb
-----
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def not_found
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render status: 404 }
    end
  end

  def internal_server_error
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render status: 500 }
    end
  end
end

---> these work so I wont paste the content here.
app/views/errors/not_found.html.erb
app/views/errors/internal_server_error.html.erb
```

Is this the right approach?  If Yes, what am I missing or not understanding.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add these in your top level (application) controller and rescue accordingly. Some sample code from a project I'm working on:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do |e|
  puts "#{e.inspect}, PARAMS: #{params.inspect}" if Config[:verbose_tests]
  respond_with_404
end
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError do |e|
  puts "#{e.inspect}, PARAMS: #{params.inspect}" if Config[:verbose_tests]
  respond_with_404
end
rescue_from Pundit::NotAuthorizedError do
  respond_with_403
end
```

In your case, this would be something like:

```
// app/controllers/application_controller.rb

rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound do
  not_found
end
rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError do
  not_found
end
rescue_from ActionController::StandardError do
  internal_server_error
end
```

Make sure you have access to your `internal_server_error` and `not_found` methods inside your application controller, you can even define them there, and then when the error is thrown your app should respond accordingly.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure what you mean by: `Make sure you have access to your internal_server_error and not_found methods inside your application controller`  I added your suggested code to `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`  I still get the error.

Comment: The easiest way is to just copy and paste the method definitions from your errors_controller (`not_found` and `internal_server_error`) into your application controller. Otherwise your application controller will error out as it won't know what the methods `not_found` and `internal_server_error` do

Comment: Thanks for the help.   It is still not working.  I'm not able to copy/paste my code here.  It loses it's formatting.   But, I have the methods from my controller and the rescue blocks you mentioned all in my `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`